# jointed articulate animals (do we need 'jointed' here?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> jointed articulate animals

I think 'jointed' and 'articulate' are overlapping.

Do we really need the word 'jointed' here? Or can we omit that?

Comment: I think you mean *articulated*: having two or more sections connected by a flexible joint. This is somewhat synonymous with *jointed*. However, *articulate* doesn't mean the same.

Comment: @BillyKerr not the same as you said but doesn't it(articulate) have the meaning of 'having the qualities of being articulated' as an adjective? Or does it only relate to/with 'in pronunciation or speech' as an adjective?

Comment: it can in some very technical use-cases, but "articulated" is the correct word to use in your example when referring to animals of this type, otherwise it sounds like you are talking about an animal that can talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do - because otherwise, it sounds like your animals can talk. The primary definition of 'articulate' is the ability to express your thoughts and emotions well through speech.

The medical use of the word refers to the workings of two or more body parts, in particular the way in which the parts are joined and able to move in relation to each other. This could refer to the jaw (hence the previously mentioned definition) or any other joint such as in limbs. So it seems necessary to specify what area of articulation you are referring to - in this case, the joints.